# Update html table via servlet and jsp

Tags: java, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, tablesorter

I am creating a simple Java webpage which has to get input from user and then push the data to table which is on the same page. Everything is working perfectly. Each time the user gives input the page, the servlet does it job and reloads the page and table is updated. My question is, how to update table without reloading the page.

Secondly, i have a input field, which searches the table. Again, it is working. However, I'm also trying to add jquerys tablesorter to my table. I have done everything according to tutorials but the sorting isn't happening. Can this be because of the search field? I am also using Bootstrap to design my table, can this be the cause (although the jquerys tablesorter states, that it works with Bootstrap also).

The servlet returns with:

```
request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);;
```

**UPDATE**
My JSP looks like this:
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
  <title>My title</title>
  <link href="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css"    rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/myStyle.css" rel="stylesheet">    
</head>
<body>
  <form  method="post" >
   <div class="container">
    <div class="jumbotron">
            <label for="name">Nimi</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control"/>
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control"/>
            <label for="syKP">Sünnikuupäev</label>
            <input type="text" name="syKP" class="form-control"/>
            <label for="aadress">Aadress</label>
            <input type="text" name="aadress" class="form-control"/><br>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md">Add</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
<div class="container">
 <div class="jumbotron">
  <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Type to search"><br>
   <table class="table table-hover tablesorter" id="tabel">
<thead>
 <tr>
    <th>Nimi</th>
    <th>Aadress</th>
    <th>Synd</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Muuda</th>
    <th>Kustuta</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
<c:forEach items="${dataLst.getData()}" var="person">
 <tbody id="table">
  <tr >
    <td><c:out value="${person.getNimi()}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${person.getAadress()}"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${person.getSynniKP() }"/></td>
    <td><c:out value="${person.getEmail()}"/></td>
    <td><button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button></td>
    <td><button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-    remove-sign"></span></button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</c:forEach>   
</table>
</div>
</div>
<script src="webjars/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="webjars/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and my servlet file like this:

```
package com.energy;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/login.do")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

DataList dataLst = new DataList();

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
throws ServletException, IOException{
    request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp").forward(request,response);
}

protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) 
throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String aadress = request.getParameter("aadress");
    String syKP = request.getParameter("syKP");



    PersonData person = new PersonData(name, aadress, syKP, email);
    dataLst.addPerson(person);
    //request.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
    //request.setAttribute("email", request.getParameter("email"));
    //System.out.println(dataLst.getData().get(0).getNimi());

    request.setAttribute("dataLst",dataLst);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp").forward(request,     response);;
}

}
```

Comment: To load table without page reload, instead of submitting the form directly, use ajax to submit the form. Also, can you provide code for webpage and servlet? It'll help you get faster responses here at stack overflow.

Comment: AJAX should be the best solution probably yes, but I don't exactly know how to use it in this project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For updating the table dynamically:**

Usually, JSON is used to send response from the server. Use [GSON.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/gson/gson-2.2.2.jar.zip) to convert a java object to corresponding JSON. This is replacing the request dispatcher in servlet as shown in the updated servlet class below-

```
package com.energy;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.MultipartConfig;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/login.do")
@MultipartConfig
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  DataList dataLst = new DataList();

  protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{
  }

  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String address = request.getParameter("aadress");
    String syKP = request.getParameter("syKP");

    PersonData person = new PersonData(name, address, syKP, email);
    dataLst.addPerson(person);
    //request.setAttribute("name", request.getParameter("name"));
    //request.setAttribute("email", request.getParameter("email"));
    //System.out.println(dataLst.getData().get(0).getNimi());

    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    Gson data = new Gson();
    String tmp = data.toJson(dataLst); // won't work if you don't assign it to a string.
    response.getWriter().write(tmp);
    //request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp").forward(request,     response);;
  }

}
```

For submitting the form using ajax (to avoid page reloads), I've modified your form as this-

```
<form  method="post" id="loginForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

The `multipart-form-data` helps serialize the form in a standard way (HTML5). Now make your servlet capable of accepting `multipart`requests by addding `@MultipartConfig` annotation as shown below-

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns="/login.do")
@MultipartConfig
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet{
    // Rest of the code.
}
```

We're almost there! Now if you prefer JavaScript, add the following function to your `main.js` to make the ajax calls.

```
function addData(){
  if(window.XMLHttpRequest) { //Assuming you're not on one of the old IEs.
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var myArr = JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
            //console.log(myArr);
            addToTable(myArr); // function to add data to table.

        }
    }
    xhttp.open("POST","login.do",true);
    var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('loginForm'));
    xhttp.send(formData);
  }
  else console.log('not working');
}
```

Make sure you call this function on click of `Add` button.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-md" onclick="addData();">Add</button>
```

Here's one of the ways to write `addToTable` function.

```
function addToTable(data) {
  var dataTable = document.getElementById("tabel");
  for(var i = 0; i<data.pList.length; i++) {
    var row = dataTable.insertRow();
    var tmp = data.pList[i];

    var cell0 = row.insertCell(); //nimi
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(); //aadress
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(); //synd
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(); //email
    var cell4 = row.insertCell(); //muuda
    var cell5 = row.insertCell(); //kustuta

    cell0.innerHTML = tmp.name;
    cell1.innerHTML = tmp.address;
    cell2.innerHTML = tmp.syKP;
    cell3.innerHTML = tmp.email;
    cell4.innerHTML = '<button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
    cell5.innerHTML = '<button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button>';
  }
}
```

Note that `pList` is the name of list in `DataList.java` where I'm storing `PersonDetails`.

If you're comfortable with jQuery, same thing can be done as follows-

```
$(function() {
  $('button[type=button]').on('click',function() {
    var upForm = $('form').get(0);
    var $form = new FormData(upForm);
    $.ajax({
        url:'login.do', 
        data: $form,
        type: 'POST',
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function(responseText) {
            var data = responseText.pList;
            $.each(data, function(index, tmp) {
                var table1 = $('table>tbody').get(0);
                var row = table1.insertRow();
                var cell0 = row.insertCell(); //nimi
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(); //aadress
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(); //synd
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(); //email
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(); //muuda
                var cell5 = row.insertCell(); //kustuta

                cell0.innerHTML = tmp.name;
                cell1.innerHTML = tmp.address;
                cell2.innerHTML = tmp.syKP;
                cell3.innerHTML = tmp.email;
                cell4.innerHTML = '<button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></button>';
                cell5.innerHTML = '<button class="btn button-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span></button>';
            });
            $('#tabel').tablesorter();
        }
    });
  });
})
```

The `servlet` and `html` configuration will remain the same.

P.S. I've removed the code jstl code because I've always had hard time tweaking jQuery and bootstrap with the jstl translated code.

Also, `tablesorter` works fine for me. Though I don't have the search box implemented, I don't think it will cause any problem for `tablesorter`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your well explained answer but I still have one question. The first part, where I use Gson, should I put it in my servlet and just replace the line
`request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/views/Login.jsp").forward(request, response);`

with what you provided? Because if I do so, it get error which states "Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to Gson.`

Comment: Thank you, this clears this part. Although, I have to keep the line in doGet(..) also, otherwise my page just wont show anything. Any ideas, why is it like that? Also, now I'm running into a new problem. If I insert data and click ADD, error pops up

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
 com.energy.LoginServlet.doPost(LoginServlet.java:49)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
 org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)`

Comment: I have Gson in dependencies 

`<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>`

Comment: Ok, changed the dependacy to 
` <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.2</version>
  </dependency>`

which solved the problem.

Comment: Now if I do this, I end up in message on console
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/json: "http://localhost:8080/".`
The page shows info of what i have inputed.
`{"data":[{"nimi":"kldkld","aadress":"sdf","synniKP":"0003-02-03","email":"silver@ut.ee","id":0},{"nimi":"kldkld","aadress":"sdf","synniKP":"0003-02-03","email":"silver@ut.ee","id":1}]}`

Comment: So, for you, is the page still reloading? Have you commented the part of request dispatcher? Also, seeing your JSON, you need to replace every instance of `pList` with `data` in javascrtipt/jQuery.

Comment: I have done the replaced all instances of pList with data. Also in doPost, I have commented out the dispatcher part. It still remains in doGet part because if I remove it from the, the page isn't loading. And the page reloads well, the output is the json data I commented above.

Comment: I can't understand the issue you're facing. Need to see your whole code. Do you have a git or bitbucket account? Otherwise you can zip your whole project and mail it to develop.abhij03@gmail.com

Comment: Got the issues and fixed them. How do you want them?

Comment: You can email them to me vaderike@hotmail.com